# In Scala, how do I get the text of a XML node without the text of its subnodes?

Tags: scala, xml-parsing

I have an XML file, where I have a specific node which always has text, and also may have a child or not. After reading it in Scala, the Node element can look like one of those:

```
val nodeWithChild = <cell colorbg="16777215">
              independent
              <grid>
            <row>
              <cell colorbg="16777215">
                exclusively
              </cell>
            </row>
              </grid>
            </cell>
val nodeWithoutChild = <cell colorbg="16777215">
              dependent
            </cell>
```

Now I want to get the text of the parent node. And I expected the `text` method to give it to me.

```
scala> nodeWithChild.text
res0: String = 
"
              independent



                exclusively



            "

scala> nodeWithoutChild.text
res1: String = 
"
              dependent
            "
```

Getting rid of the whitespace is no problem. But the problem is that, in the first case, I don't want the word `exclusively` in my results. I only want a result which reads `independent`.

How do I get at this text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `child` method of the `Elem` to get its children (and not the rest of its descendants), and then `collect` (or `filter`, or `flatMap`, etc.) to select only the text nodes:

```
scala> val texts = nodeWithChild.child.collect { case Text(t) => t }
texts: Seq[String] = 
ArrayBuffer("
              independent
              ", "
            ")
```

And if you want to ignore whitespace:

```
scala> texts.map(_.trim).filterNot(_.isEmpty)
res3: Seq[String] = ArrayBuffer(independent)
```

You could also do this filtering in the same pass as the text node selection by adding something like  `if t.trim.nonEmpty` to the case.

Comment: Thank you, I am just starting out with Scala and wasn't aware that the text of a node is considered a child.